# Почему нельзя вставлять код строками в jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть обычная функция .append, есть пример большого кода который надо вставлять, например:

```html
<div class="form category">
   <h4>Столешница</h4>
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">
         <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Площадь столешницы</p>
         <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">24м2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">
          <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Цена столешницы</p>
          <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">5000 руб.</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Когда вставляю код в .append так как он есть - выскакивает ошибка всегда, чтоб ее устранить надо записать весь html в строку, например:

```
 $('.results_block').append('<div class="form category"><h4>Столешница</h4><div class="col-xs-12 onem"><p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Площадь столешницы</p><span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">24м2</span></div><div class="col-xs-12 onem"><p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Цена столешницы</p><span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">5000 руб.</span></div></div>');
```

Это совсем не удобно и как-то странно. Может кто-то сказать в чем причина или как удобней делать?

Comment: что значит _вставляю код в .append так как он есть_? Какая именно ошибка выскакивает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему нельзя вставлять код строками в jQuery.
>   Это совсем не удобно и как-то странно. Может кто-то сказать в чем причина или как удобней делать?

В коллекцию, [строковой литерал](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```js
var data = `
<div class="form category">
   <h4>Столешница</h4>
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">
         <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Площадь столешницы</p>
         <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">24м2</span>
      </div>\
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">
          <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Цена столешницы</p>
          <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">5000 руб.</span>
      </div>
 </div>
 `;
  $('.results_block').append(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results_block"></div>
```

Comment: тоже крутой способ, раньше не читал, спасибо)

Comment: Этот способ **поддерживается только** в Chrome, Firefox и Opera. Остальные обозреватели сети выдают ошибку. **Правильно будет в конце каждой строки писать "\" для экранирования знака "перенос строки".**

Answer (score 2):

Потому что переносы строк в inline многострочных строках в js коде надо обозначать "\". Рассматривайте это как эскейп символ перед невидимым символом новой строки.

```js
var data = '\
<div class="form category">\
   <h4>Столешница</h4>\
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">\
         <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Площадь столешницы</p>\
         <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">24м2</span>\
      </div>\
      <div class="col-xs-12 onem">\
          <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Цена столешницы</p>\
          <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">5000 руб.</span>\
      </div>\
 </div>\
 ';
  $('.results_block').append(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results_block"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот тут понял, буду использовать)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, если я правильно понял о чем вы.

```js
var html = '<div class="form category">' +
   '<h4>Столешница</h4>' +
      '<div class="col-xs-12 onem">' +
         '<p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Площадь столешницы</p>' +
         '<span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">24м2</span>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-xs-12 onem">' +
          '<p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Цена столешницы</p>' +
          '<span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">5000 руб.</span>' +
      '</div>' +
 '</div>'
$('.results_block').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results_block"></div>
```

Comment: Нуу.. в принципе данный код немного решает проблему - легче ориентироваться в коде. Но всё же я хотел узнать почему обычный перенос строки в файле - причина ошибки.